# Recharts Responsive Container does not resize correctly in flexbox

Tags: css, reactjs, user-interface, flexbox, recharts

I'm trying to create a custom collapsable legend for my data visualization app. It uses react and recharts. the component renders nicely the first time. But when I collapse the legend and reopen it, the responsive container doesn't shrink to fit. This would be easier if I knew the size of the parent container in pixels but I don't have that information on render. Is this a bug with recharts or flex box or am I doing it wrong?

Heres the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/8krz9qjk52

Clarification: The problem is that when I close and then open the legend, the legend component gets pushed out of the viewing area and the chart does not shrink back to the original smaller size.

Answer (score 43):

It seems rather hacky but a viable fix is to set width to 99% with a height or aspect ratio.

`<ResponsiveContainer width="99%" aspect={3}>`

See this issue:

https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/172

Comment: This worked for me. I don't know why this works. Appreciate it if someone can shed the light on this issue.

Comment: HOW? Because this one is working :D

Comment: typescript says it needs a number

Comment: ts also says aspect doesn't exist

Answer (score 11):

I know this is a really old issue, but I'm posting here just in case somebody else lands here via Google.

I don't know **why** this works, but setting `position: absolute` on `.recharts-wrapper` will fix this issue entirely. So far I have found no downsides to this, but YRMV.

Comment: I am having this issue and can't figure out how to fix it using any of the google'd issues including this one.  Anyone else have fixes?

Answer (score 6):

try this, it resolved the responsiveness (resizing) for both width and height

```js
<div style={{position: 'relative', width: '100%', paddingBottom: '250px'}}>
  <div
    style={{
      position: 'absolute',
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      top: 0,
    }}
  >
    <ResponsiveContainer>
      <YourChartGoesHere />
    </ResponsiveContainer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please check again if this works without any error mesaage ERROR: {
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 12,
  "colno": 9
}

Answer (score 3):

The Best bet is to give it a width of 100% then play around with the aspect ratio till if satisfys you. I did this to adapt to different screen sizes

```
const theme = useTheme(); //this is from mui
const isMobile = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down("sm"));

<ResponsiveContainer width="100%" aspect={isMobile?1.5:1.8}>
```

Works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm having similar problems in my project, I decided to stick with this question. I was finally able to get a working solution!

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xpz8y5w77w)

I'll list the changes I made from biggest to smallest:

> I [lifted state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)
>   from `CustomLegend` to `CustomChart`.

- Now, `CustomChart` is in charge of what happens. It passes visibility information to `CustomLegend` as a prop. How does `CustomChart` know when to change state?
- `CustomChart` has a member function called `handleButtonClick` that sets its state. `handleButtonClick` is sent to `CustomLegend` as a prop. So `CustomChart` renders `CustomLegend` like this:

  ```
  <CustomLegend
      items={legendData}
      onClick={this.handleButtonClick}
      legendVisible={this.state.legendVisible}
  />
  ```

  Now in `CustomLegend`, we can include this in the `button` definition: `onClick={this.props.onClick}` Note that this pattern only works if the original function is bound to the parent since it alters the parent's state.

> `chart-container` is now a [CSS
>   Grid](https://gridbyexample.com/examples/) container.

- It renders an inline style handling the column width based on state.

  ```
  <div
      className="chart-container"
      style={{
        gridTemplateColumns: this.state.legendVisible
          ? "80% 1fr"
          : "1fr min-content"
      }}
  >
  ```

  Note that `1fr` is a fractional unit which, in this case, serves to fill the remaining space.
- In `styles.css`, `grid-auto-flow` is set to `column` which allows things to be placed in the grid as columns. The things we place into the grid are `SampleChart` and `CustomLegend`, so `SampleChart` is the left column and `CustomLegend` is the right column.
- `gridTemplateColumns: 80% 1fr`: When the legend is visible, we want the left column to take up 80% of the width and the right column to fill the rest.
- `gridTemplateColumns: 1fr min-content`: When the legend is invisible, we want the right column to take up the minimum amount of space which its elements fill and the left column to fill the remaining space.

> `CustomLegend` has only a single `render` method.

- Instead of `renderVisible` and `renderHidden`, there is one method which conditionally renders the `legend-list` based on props (dependent on `CustomChart`'s state).
- The `legend-container` always renders now (it is a grid item).

> Other small changes:

- In `SampleChart`: `<ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height="100%" className={props.className}>` This has been changed because `<SampleChart className="chart-area" data={data} />` actually sends `className` as a prop. Be careful with this! You need to set `className` directly on the parent tag in `SampleChart`'s returned hierarchy (in this case the `ResponsiveContainer`). Try going back to your [original codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/8krz9qjk52) and changing the `background-color` on `chart-area` in `styles.css` (nothing happens!).
- `overflow: scroll` in all instances from `styles.css` because we no longer need it.

You'll notice that if you attempt a grid layout using only `fr` units or any flex layout on `chart-container`, that the chart doesn't resize properly. Unfortunately, Recharts' `ResponsiveContainer`s just don't play nicely with Grid or Flexbox (the project's main contributors are gradually tapering off support – [no commits](https://github.com/recharts/recharts/graphs/commit-activity) in 3 months as of now).

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your `styles.css`:

```
html, body, #root {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

otherwise `.chart-container`, even though its width and height are set to 100%, will not take up the entire viewport. Then in `SampleChart.jsx`, change this:

```
<ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height={400}>
```

to this:

```
<ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height="100%">
```

to make your `ResponsiveContainer`'s height... well, responsive.

Comment: that doest help. When I close and then open the legend, the legend component get pushed out of the viewing area and the chart does not shrink back to the original smaller size

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted the question. Check out my second answer!